# Return a percentage column using self-join with WHERE clause filtering on the numerator only

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, self-join, ambiguity

UPDATE May 31, 2018: Included a SQLFiddle, in the hopes that somebody can figure out a solution.

The following function contains two CTE's named QuirksCTE and SurplusCTE. *Both* of these CTE's should filter the numerator of a fraction, while the denominator of that fraction should inherit *only* the filtering effect of QuirksCTE. The object is to produce a percentage (a subset divided by a set). The numerator and denominator of said fraction are related to each other through a self-join. The core of the problem is this: I remain unable to selectively apply 2 CTE filters to the numerator of this SELF-JOIN while only applying 1 of those CTE filters to the denominator. Every attempt so far to rearrange and restructure the where clause and the joins has resulted in the denominator ignoring all filters and instead picking up every row of the data (there are 7 rows in the sample database). Note that in the end I will use the FORMAT function to handle the fraction's transformation into a percentage, but for now I'm ignoring that more cosmetic task.

To use the fiddle linked to below, you should give the function an input parameter from this little table. My manual calculations predict the associated "Correct Output Parameter," which I am so far unable to arrive at using SQL.

```
Input Parameter       Correct Output Parameter
     0                       0
     1                      .5
     2                      .666
     3                      .666
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ae5a1/1
(Requires a function call and an input variable from chart shown above).

```
--This is a user defined function containing 2 CTE's and a SELECT 
--statement with 2 joins and a WHERE clause. I included that structural 
--detail in case it makes a difference.


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExampleOfQueryStructure] 
(
    @MyInputParameter int
)
RETURNS 
@MyOutputParameter TABLE 
(
    [MyPercentage] float          
)
AS
BEGIN
WITH    Quirks_CTE (AnimalDateTime, Quirks) 
        AS   
           (SELECT 
               AnimalDateTime,
               (COALESCE (Lion, 0) + COALESCE (Zebra, 0) 
               + COALESCE (Antelope, 0) + COALESCE (Giraffe, 0)) 
           FROM dbo.tblAnimals),

        Surplus_CTE 
        AS
           (SELECT 
               JobEntryDateTime,
               CASE 
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel5-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel5
               END AS [5_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel8-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel8
               END AS [8_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel20-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel20
               END AS [20_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevelStone-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevelStone
               END AS [StoneProfit]

        FROM dbo.tblJobEntries)


INSERT INTO @MyOutputParameter ([MyPercentage])
   SELECT 
       COUNT(a.Quirks)/COUNT(b.Quirks)
       FROM QuirksCTE b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN QuirksCTE a 
           ON b.AnimalDateTime = a.AnimalDateTime
              where exists(select 1 from Surplus_CTE c
                           where a.AnimalDateTime = c.JobEntryDateTime
                           AND ([5_SURPLUS] > 0 OR [8_SURPLUS] > 0 
                                OR [20_SURPLUS] > 0 OR [StoneProfit] > 0)   
                           AND a.Quirks <= @MyInputParameter)

RETURN
END
```

---

Comment: sorry,now I am paying attention to your query.yes it all always return 1 as per your query in Quirks_CTE. Nobody can correct it because understood your requirement and there is no sample data to correct it.So throw sample data in text format and outline your output.

Comment: Try moving your exists clause (that filters the quirks "a" table) as another condition on the LEFT JOIN rather than being on the WHERE.

Comment: Your description of what you want is unclear. PS Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: @JasperS3000 I can't arrive to your desired outcome for parameter 1 (value of 0.5) with your current data and your business logic, can you break down the records to arriving at 0.5?

Comment: @EzLo An input parameter of 1 dictates that, in tblAnimals table, only rows having a total of 1 "Quirk" are considered. There are 4 such rows. That (should) become our denominator. To establish our numerator, we now look at the tblJobEntries table and inspect those rows which share the same date as those rows in the denominator-- just established-- and we count the number of same-date numerator rows which produce a surplus > 0 from at least one of the CASE statements. There are 2 such rows, and so we are left with a numerator of 2, a denominator of 4, which in decimal form equals .5.

Comment: @JasperS3000 you are filtering with lower or equal (`<=`) instead of just equal in your parameter. So for value 1 you are also counting the ones that are 0, so there aren't 4 records but 5. Also the surplus is > 0 for 3 or those records, not just 2. See my edited answer and you will see.

Comment: @EzLo Fantastic strategy to construct an additional CTE to simplify the synthesis between the first 2 CTE's. You were right that I had some wrong data, but I've corrected that now. With the corrected data (what you've been using) an input parameter of 1 produces a result of 3/7, but it should be 3/5. This suggests the denominator isn't being filtered at all, and all records are being included. I tried a new test script with a function based on your revised query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a2a4  All input parameters produce an answer of .75. Correct result for input parameter of 1 should be .6

Comment: @JasperS3000 Currently for an input = 1, it's doing the division 3/4 (0.75) as there are only 4 records with Quirks = 1, maybe you want to filter by lower or equal instead of equal? If you do `WHERE b.Quirks <= @MyInputParameter` then you consider the record with Quirks = 0 and the division becomes 3/5 (0.6).

Comment: @EzLo  Whew! I can't believe it works at last! You were spot on about the numerator having <= while the denominator had =. Also, I looked again at your updated solution and realized that you just temporarily hard-coded 1 as an input variable. After I replaced the hard-coded '1' with [asperand]MyInputParameter your "extra CTE" code delivers the correct results. I will study all of this and learn from it. I do have one question before I close the subject-- why do you multiply the numerator by 1 in the Select query? On the surface it seems like a circular exercise.

Comment: @JasperS3000 the division of 2 integers (the count() function returns integers) has an integer result (in SQL Server). So if you do `SELECT 99/100` the result is 0 as it is truncated because both numbers are infered as integers. If either of those is converted to float or decimal (for example by multiplying it with a decimal `1.0` - note the dot) then it becomes a decimal and the result of the division has decimal numbers. `SELECT 99 * 1.0 / 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your `WHERE` is making your `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN` (thus rendering both counts the same) since you are forcing the records to match on their date. This is the corrected function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExampleOfQueryStructure] 
(
    @MyInputParameter int
)
RETURNS 
@MyOutputParameter TABLE 
(
    [MyPercentage] float
)
AS
BEGIN
WITH    Quirks_CTE (AnimalDateTime, Quirks) 
        AS   
           (SELECT 
               AnimalDateTime,
               (COALESCE (Lion, 0) + COALESCE (Zebra, 0) 
               + COALESCE (Antelope, 0) + COALESCE (Giraffe, 0)) 
           FROM dbo.tblAnimals),

        Surplus_CTE 
        AS
           (SELECT 
               JobEntryDateTime,
               CASE 
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel5-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel5
               END AS [5_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel8-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel8
               END AS [8_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel20-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel20
               END AS [20_SURPLUS]
            FROM dbo.tblJobEntries)

INSERT INTO @MyOutputParameter ([MyPercentage])
   SELECT 
       COUNT(a.Quirks) * 1.0 /COUNT(b.Quirks)
       FROM Quirks_CTE b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Quirks_CTE a 
           ON b.AnimalDateTime = a.AnimalDateTime
              AND exists(select 1 from Surplus_CTE c
                           where a.AnimalDateTime = c.JobEntryDateTime
                           AND ([5_SURPLUS] > 0 OR [8_SURPLUS] > 0 
                                OR [20_SURPLUS] > 0)   
                           AND a.Quirks <= @MyInputParameter)

RETURN
END
```

I also changed the return value to float (integer would return only 0 or 1).

---

**EDIT:** Use this query to validate your data. It's a lot simpler if you join the surplus with the animal count before on another CTE, as the join is always by date.

```
WITH    Quirks_CTE (AnimalDateTime, Quirks) 
        AS   
           (SELECT 
               AnimalDateTime,
               (COALESCE (Lion, 0) + COALESCE (Zebra, 0) 
               + COALESCE (Antelope, 0) + COALESCE (Giraffe, 0)) 
           FROM dbo.tblAnimals),

        Surplus_CTE 
        AS
           (SELECT 
               JobEntryDateTime,
               CASE 
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel5-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel5
               END AS [5_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel8-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel8
               END AS [8_SURPLUS],

               CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevel20-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevel20
               END AS [20_SURPLUS],

              CASE
                  WHEN tblJobEntries.Stance = 1
                  THEN ExitLevelStone-BeginLevel
                  ELSE BeginLevel-ExitLevelStone
               END AS [StoneSurplus]            

            FROM dbo.tblJobEntries),
       AnimalSurplus AS
       (
         SELECT
           Q.AnimalDateTime,
           Q.Quirks,
           Surplus = CASE WHEN [5_SURPLUS] > 0 OR [8_SURPLUS] > 0 OR [20_SURPLUS] > 0 OR [StoneSurplus] > 0 THEN 1 END
         FROM
           Quirks_CTE AS Q
           LEFT JOIN Surplus_CTE AS S ON Q.AnimalDateTime = S.JobEntryDateTime
         )
   -- SELECT * FROM AnimalSurplus
   SELECT 
       COUNT(a.Quirks) * 1.0 /COUNT(b.Quirks)
       FROM AnimalSurplus b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN AnimalSurplus a 
           ON b.AnimalDateTime = a.AnimalDateTime AND a.Surplus = 1
       WHERE b.Quirks <= @MyInputParameter
```

Comment: Your float datatype change was centrally important. However, your Select statement produces wrong results because, based on my manual calculations of this test data, the denominator is still not picking up the filter intended by a.Quirks <= @MyInputParameter. All 7 rows of data are being counted for the denominator, no matter what input parameter is plugged in. What should happen is both numerator and denominator get restricted by a.Quirks <=MyInputParameter, and another restriction (embodied by the "SURPLUS" brackets) only filters the numerator. Correct answer for an input of '2' is '.666'